# Call a method on a variable where the method name is in another variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<% @labels.each do |label| %>
    <input type="text" name="<%=label.name%>" value="<%=@car.(label.related_to) %>" class="big-font" style="width: <%=label.width%>px; top: <%=label.y_coor%>px; left: <%=label.x_coor%>px;" /> 
<% end %>
```

Hello guys, I'm new to rails so this should be a fairly easy question to answer.

The issue is here: `<%=@car.(label.related_to) %>`.

label.related_to holds the string "make". I'm trying to get it to do this pretty much: `@car.make`

Any idea guys?

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `send` to send a message to an object:

```
@car.send(label.related_to)
```

If there is any chance of `label.related_to` not being a valid method for the object, you'll probably want to be prepared to catch the `NoMethodError`

Comment: ... and just wait when label.ralated_to will become to "destroy"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `try` method.

```
<%= car.try(label.related_to) %>
```

`try` would try to call the method on `car`. However, if the method (ie. `make`) does not exist it would throw an error.

You could make use of `respond_to?` to ensure that the method exist:

```
<%= car.try(label.related_to) if car.respond_to?(label.related_to) %>
```