# Calling a method using the string/variable of the method name inRuby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn a string into a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317298/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-method-call)

Currently I have a code that is doing something like this

```
def execute
  case @command
    when "sing"
      sing()
    when "ping"
      user_defined_ping()
    when "--help|-h|help"
      get_usage()      
end
```

I find the case pretty useless and huge and I had like to call the appropriate method just by using the variable @command. Something like:

```
def execute
 @command()
end
```

Offcourse I would not need and extra execute() method in this case.

Any suggestions on how I can acheive this ruby ?

Thanks!

Edit: 
Added other method type for multiple strings. Not sure if that can also be handled in an elegant manner.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800836/call-a-method-on-a-variable-where-the-method-name-is-in-another-variable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317298/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-method-call and probably many others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [send](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Object%3asend)

`send(@command) if respond_to?(@command)`

The `respond_to?` ensures that `self` responds to this method before attempting to execute it

For the updated `get_usage()` part I would use something similar to this:

```
def execute
  case @command
  when '--help', '-h', 'help'
    get_usage()
  # more possibilities
  else
    if respond_to?(@command)
      send(@command)
    else
      puts "Unknown command ..."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: beautiful !! thnkx @injekt  ..is there also something for get_usage() method I added in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `send` probably. Take a look at this: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999

```
def execute
    send @command
end
```